# Encoding with OrdinalEncoder: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, pandas, numpy, encoding

I am trying to do a Random Forest in a dataset with numerical and categorical variables in order to obtain a categorical result (two possible classes, column name "predicción"). I am using the scikit-learn library in Jupyter notebook.

I have done the train-test split like this:

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(datos.drop(columns = 'predicción'), datos['predicción'],random_state = 123)
```

then I made two lists with the column names that hold numerical or categorical values:

```
cat_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns.to_list()
numeric_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int']).columns.to_list()

cat = list(np.array(cat_cols).reshape(1,9))
```

I then do the encoding using ColumnTransformer:

```
niveles = ['0', '1', '2']
encoder = ColumnTransformer([('ordinal', OrdinalEncoder(categories=[niveles]), cat)],remainder='passthrough')
```

So far so good, no errors up to this point. The error rises when I use the `fit_transform`:

```
X_train = encoder.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test  = encoder.fit_transform(X_test)
```

I have not been able to find a solution to this problem or any alternative. I am fairly new to machine learning if that can be an excuse. Any bit of help is welcome!

Comment: Remove the **fit_transform** from the test data set and just fit an **transform** on the test. That will fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `fit_transform` method on both the training and test dataset which is incorrect. You should only use `fit_transform` on the training dataset (since the encoder should only fit/learn from data in the training dataset and not the test dataset as this would be new information when deploying your model) and then use `transform` to apply the encoder on the test dataset.

Comment: I've changed the code to: 

'X_train_fit = encoder.fit(X_train)

X_train_trans = X_train_fit.transform(X_train)' 

I still get the same error, i don't know if I'm using the methods right. Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: Like I said, try using `fit_transform` for the training data and `transform` for the test data. In addition, check the data types of your `X_train`, `cat` variables and try changing `categories=[niveles]` to `categories=niveles` since `niveles` already is a list.